# Cargo Collective - Hover image on background when hovering image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image gallery set up, but I want that the images show as a hover in the background before you click through onto the lightbox.

Is this possible? So in the section where it says {image 10}{image 8}{image 7}
there should be a hover function on this.

```html
<hr><div grid-row="" grid-pad="2" grid-gutter="4" grid-responsive="">
    <div grid-col="x9" grid-pad="2"><b>Project 1</b><br><span style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);">2021</span><br></div>
    <div grid-col="x9" grid-pad="2" class="">
    Text regarding project here</div>
    <div grid-col="x9" grid-pad="2" class=""><b>Area of Expertise</b><br><small><font color="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.501960784313726)"><span style="letter-spacing: 0.488678px;"><a href="RESEARCH" rel="history" data-tags="RESEARCH">Research,</a> <a href="CURATION" rel="history" data-tags="CURATION">Curation</a></span></font></small></div>
    <div grid-col="x9" grid-pad="2" class=""><div class="image-gallery" gid="75">
{image 10}
{image 8}
{image 7}
</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ive tried adding a div class to the image but it disappears when i press save on cargo